# Rx: What are subscriptions and how do subscriptions work?

Tags: c#, .net, rxjs, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I'm learning reactive extensions (rx) in .NET and I'm struggling a little bit with what a "subscription" really is and when it is used.

Lets take some sample data, taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51944853/take-first-elements-of-stream-after-previous-element-matches-condition/51945611#51945611) thread:

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        class Result
        {
            public bool Flag { get; set; }
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {               
            var source =
               Observable.Create<Result>(f =>
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Start creating data!");

                   f.OnNext(new Result() { Text = "one", Flag = false });
                   Thread.Sleep(1000);
                   f.OnNext(new Result() { Text = "two", Flag = true });
                   Thread.Sleep(1000);
                   f.OnNext(new Result() { Text = "three", Flag = false });
                   Thread.Sleep(1000);
                   f.OnNext(new Result() { Text = "four", Flag = false });
                   Thread.Sleep(1000);
                   f.OnNext(new Result() { Text = "five", Flag = true });
                   Thread.Sleep(1000);
                   f.OnNext(new Result() { Text = "six", Flag = true });
                   Thread.Sleep(1000);
                   f.OnNext(new Result() { Text = "seven", Flag = true });
                   Thread.Sleep(1000);
                   f.OnNext(new Result() { Text = "eight", Flag = false });
                   Thread.Sleep(1000);
                   f.OnNext(new Result() { Text = "nine", Flag = true });
                   Thread.Sleep(1000);
                   f.OnNext(new Result() { Text = "ten", Flag = false });

                   return () => Console.WriteLine("Observer has unsubscribed");
               });
        }
    }
}
```

Beware of the line:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Start creating data!");
```

Now, first I thought a subscription simply is used by using the `.Subscribe` operator. So an observer (e.g. the callback of the `.Subscribe` function) subscribes to an observable (the last return value of a chain of operators) like this (just as an example, the query doesn't have a real use):

```
  source.Zip(source, (s1, s0) =>
     s0.Flag
     ? Observable.Return(s1)
     : Observable.Empty<Result>()).Merge().Subscribe(f => { Console.WriteLine(f.Text); });
```

Now I was expecting to get the "Start creating data!" output only once, since I was only using one subscription. But in fact, **I got it twice**:

```
Start creating data!
Start creating data!
two
five
six
seven
nine
```

I was told that everytime I use an operator on `source.`, a subscription is made. But in this example I'm using `source.` only once and then a second time just as a parameter for the `.Zip` operator. Or is it because the source is passed to the `.Zip` function by value subscribed again?

So my questions are:

1. What exactly is a "subscription" in terms of Rx?
2. Where / why exactly do the two subscriptions happen on my example?

Btw. I know I can prevent multiple subscriptions from happening by using the `.Publish` operator, but that isn't the scope of my questions.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32263315/259769

Comment: You need to create your test observable like I did in the previous question - this `Observable.Create<Result>` method of your will cause you grief sooner or later.

Comment: thank you, I just did it because i referenced to my other question. :)
in fact i will use your .generate solution to make tests now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms a Subscription just represents an `Observable` that has been subscribed to. This process can happen either explicitly by using `.Subscribe` or implicitly by joining two or more `Observables` and then subscribing to the resulting chain.

In your case you are seeing both happen, once explicitly when you call `Subscribe` and one implicitly when you pass `source` to `Zip`, that is, there are two `Subscriptions` to the `source` `Observable`.

Why is that important? Because by default `Observables` are lazy, meaning that they will not begin processing until you subscribe to them (the product of that process being a `Subscription`), by extension this means that *any* time you subscribe to the `Observable` it will effectively begin a new stream. This behavior can be overridden like you alluded to with `Publish`, but the default is for each `Observable` to be *cold*.

In your specific case, since you are passing the same `Observable` to `Zip` it needs to subscribe to it twice, since it will be zipping together events from the two passed streams. The result is two subscriptions to the same `Observable` which each run independently of each other.

Comment: "This behavior can be overridden like you alluded to with `Publish`, but the default is for each `Observable` to be cold." - That's not entirely true. It doesn't matter if an observable is hot or cold - each subscription creates a new observable pipeline (i.e. a Subscription). There is no "default" for an observable - they can be either hot or cold. What matters is how the observable is created. Calling `.Publish` doesn't make an observable hot - it just allows the callers of the published observable to share a single underlying subscription.

Comment: Your final paragraph is spot on - especially the point "which each run independently of each other." Had the observable `source.Zip(source, (s1, s0) =>` been written as `source.Publish(ss => ss.Zip(ss, (s1, s0) =>` then two `ss` subscriptions would have still run independently of each other, but there would have only been a single subscription to `source`. That's what `.Publish` does.

Comment: so in fact, there are even three subscription here by using .Publish: one to the source and two to the "zip"?

Comment: @TobiasvonFalkenhayn - No, there are heaps more. If you take my answer to your previous question, `source.StartWith(new Result() { Flag = true }).Publish(ss => ss.Skip(1).Zip(ss, (s1, s0) => s0.Flag ? Observable.Return(s1) : Observable.Empty<Result>()).Merge());`, there are 18 subscriptions. 1 `source`, 2 `StartWith(new Result() { Flag = true })`, 3 `Publish`, 4 `ss`, 5 `.Skip(1)`, 6 `.Zip`, 7 `ss` (inside the zip), 8 `.Merge`, and then 10 for the `Observable.Return(s1) : Observable.Empty<Result>()` pair.

Comment: @TobiasvonFalkenhayn - Take a simple example: `source.Where(x => x > 10).Select(x => x * 2).Subscribe()`. The `.Subscribe()` subscribes to the `.Select`, `.Select` subscribes to the `.Where`, `.Where` subscribes to the `source`.

Comment: Yes "default" was probably a poor word choice, since I meant a default assumption rather than a default configuration, as in assume it is cold unless otherwise told. You're right though I tried to answer two questions and conflated the two answers somewhat.  Do feel free to expand on/edit it if you'd like if you feel I missed something.